# Parse Date string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8

I have a String `20120119` which represents a date in the format `'YYYYMMDD'`.

I want to parse this string into a Ruby object that represents a Date so that I can do some basic date calculation, such as diff against today's date.

I am using version 1.8.6 (requirement).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You could use the `Date.strptime` method provided in Ruby's Standard Library:

```
require 'date'
string = "20120723"
date = Date.strptime(string,"%Y%m%d")
```

Alternately, as suggested in the comments, you could use `Date.parse`, because the heuristics work correctly in this case:

```
require 'date'
string = "20120723"
date = Date.parse(string)
```

Both will raise an `ArgumentError` if the date is not valid:

```
require 'date'
Date.strptime('2012-March', '%Y-%m')
#=> ArgumentError: invalid date

Date.parse('2012-Foo') # Note that '2012-March' would actually work here
#=> ArgumentError: invalid date
```

If you also want to represent hours, minutes, and so on, you should look at [DateTime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html). DateTime also provides a `parse` method which works like the parse method on `Date`. The same goes for `strptime`.

Comment: How about parsing exception?

Comment: Is there a way to detect if a string will throw the parsing exception?

Comment: you mean like a validator? No. Per documentation `Date.parse` doesn't even function as a validator (which is why it throws an ArgumentError instead of a more meaningful one). If you want to validate time-strings you might want to take a look at some gems that are specific to such a purpose. Timeliness might be such a gem.

Comment: is there a way to add a timezone to use with this. For example, if I do `DateTime.parse("20060224")` it returns `Fri, 24 Feb 2006 00:00:00 +0000` but i need it to be in a specific timezone such as Eastern.

Comment: Depending on where you are. In a rails environment (active_support/core_ext/date_time and active_support/core_ext/time specifically), you can do the following: `DateTime.parse('20060224').in_time_zone('EST')`